Add Redirection for Tags in WordPress
I have written this rule for plugin so that whenever a tag is deleted from wp-admin, it will add a 301 redirection rule to .htaccess file. I have written almost similar code for deleted posts redirection and it is working fine. But this is not working neither for deleted category. I don't want to redirect all 404  pages to home as it will create 404 attack.
`
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Redirect Deleted Tags
Description: Redirects deleted tags to the homepage with a 301 redirect.
Version: 1.0
Author: [Your Name]
*/


function redirect_deleted_term_to_home($term_id, $tt_id, $taxonomy) {
    // Check if the term is a tag or category
    if ($taxonomy === 'post_tag' || $taxonomy === 'category') {
        // Get the term object
        $term = get_term($term_id, $taxonomy);

        // Check if the term count is 0 (indicating it's been deleted)
        if ($term && $term->count === 0) {
            // Get the home URL
            $home_url = home_url('/');
            
            // Generate the Redirect 301 rule
            $redirect_rule = "Redirect 301 " . get_term_link($term) . " $home_url\n";
            
            // Path to the .htaccess file
            $htaccess_file = ABSPATH . '.htaccess';
            
            // Check if .htaccess file exists and is writable
            if (file_exists($htaccess_file) && is_writable($htaccess_file)) {
                // Get the content of .htaccess file
                $htaccess_content = file_get_contents($htaccess_file);
                
                // Check if the redirect rule already exists
                if (strpos($htaccess_content, $redirect_rule) === false) {
                    // Append the redirect rule to .htaccess
                    file_put_contents($htaccess_file, PHP_EOL . "# Redirect deleted term to home\n" . $redirect_rule, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action('wp_insert_term', 'redirect_deleted_term_to_home', 10, 3);
?>`

I tried some other codes but it is not working.
I tried different codes but did not work

I have this discussion with my clients from time to time. First, users don’t bookmark anywhere near as much as they used to, so the major entry point of users to dead category pages is search engines. Second, the way to kill off dead pages is to use 404 or 410. Yes, 301 works, too, but it only leads to user frustration. If some SEOs into a site and gets sent to the home page, they will probably go back and try again, possibly several times. There’s absolutely nothing wrong with presenting users with “this page no longer exists”, especially if you can say “but you might like this instead”

“this is not working” - what isn’t? The hook isn’t firing, the htaccess file isn’t being updated, the redirect isn’t happening?

@ChrisHaas htaccess file is not being updated. And that's why redirection is not happening as no rule is being written in htaccess when I delete a tag

Okay, so from that information I'm assuming that that means you've confirmed that the hooks is indeed firing. I'm seeing 4 if statements in your code without corresponding else statements. My next recommendation would be to confirm that each of those are firing correctly. A simple way is to throw a die; in each else clause, proving they aren't being reached. Lastly, file_put_contents can return false, you should inspect that result.
